# Reproductibility in multiprocessing where task contain random

Tags: python, random, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm facing some issues, we had to put a convergente algorithm in parallel to make it faster, results from the algorithm are satisfactory from business view. But for audit reason (and because business ask for it.... ) we need to make it reproducible.

Context:

- Task contains random generator usage
- Task takes more or less time because a lot of conditional in the task (so will be dispatch to different workers each run) here I put sleep to mimic the function
- Real condition are: NB_WORKER=10,NB_OBJECT=1030, NB_ITER=100
- Python 3.7 -  Windows

I though of given each object_ the responsibility of random generator .... but don't know if it's a good idea and if I will lose computation time.

Here are a snippet of code simplified :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool,get_context
from time import sleep
from numpy import random as nprng
import random
from datetime import datetime

class Object(): 
    def __init__(self,id_): 
        self.id_=id_
        self.value=0


def task(object_):
    sleep(random.random()) # task taking random time to execute (because lot of conditional)
    object_.value=rng.uniform()
    return object_

def init_worker(client_id,generators): 
        global rng
        global worker_id
        with client_id.get_lock():
            globals()['client_id'] = client_id.value
            worker_id=globals()['client_id']
            rng=nprng.Generator(generators[globals()['client_id']])
            client_id.value += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Init Pool and workers with random generators
    NB_PROCESS=5
    NB_OBJECT=34
    NB_ITER=3

    ctx = get_context("spawn")
    client_ids = ctx.Value('i', 0)
    sequences = [nprng.SeedSequence((1209391983918, worker_id)) for worker_id in range(NB_PROCESS)]
    generators = [nprng.PCG64(seq) for seq in sequences]    
    p=Pool(processes=NB_PROCESS,initializer=init_worker, initargs=(client_ids,generators,))
    
    # Parallel task

    objects=[Object(i) for i in range(NB_OBJECT)]
    arg=[(object_,) for object_ in objects]

    start=datetime.now()
    total_sum=0
    for i in range(NB_ITER):
        res=p.starmap(task,arg)
        
        total_sum+=sum([o.value for o in res])

    print(f'Total sum is : {total_sum}')
    end=datetime.now()
    print(end-start)
```

So I tried to add random generator to objects:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool,get_context
from time import sleep
from numpy import random as nprng
import random
from datetime import datetime
class Object(): 
    def __init__(self,id_,generator): 
        self.id_=id_
        self.value=0
        self.rng=nprng.Generator(generator)


def task(object_):
    sleep(random.random()) #task taking random time to execute (because lot of conditional)
    object_.value=object_.rng.uniform()
    return object_

def init_worker(client_id): 
        # global rng
        global worker_id
        with client_id.get_lock():
            globals()['client_id'] = client_id.value
            client_id.value += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Init Pool and workers with random generators
    NB_PROCESS=5
    NB_OBJECT=1030
    NB_ITER=3

    ctx = get_context("spawn")
    client_ids = ctx.Value('i', 0)
  
    p=Pool(processes=NB_PROCESS,initializer=init_worker, initargs=(client_ids,))
    
    # Parallel task
    sequences = [nprng.SeedSequence((1209391983918, worker_id)) for worker_id in range(NB_OBJECT)]
    generators = [nprng.PCG64(seq) for seq in sequences]  
    objects=[Object(i,generators[i]) for i in range(NB_OBJECT)]
    arg=[(object_,) for object_ in objects]

    start=datetime.now()
    total_sum=0
    for i in range(NB_ITER):
        res=p.starmap(task,arg)
        total_sum+=sum([o.value for o in res])

    print(f'Total sum is : {total_sum}')
    end=datetime.now()
    print(end-start)
```

But it seems to be more time consuming maybe because of object access?

Any other idea of how to reach reproducibility when parallel tasks use random in it?

Comment: Sorry - I am not in a mood to follow through your code right now - but random results in Python are controlable by setting the `seed` before each call, or sequence of calls to the random functions - https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed

Comment: You actually should call `seed` on the beginning of code in a suprocess. If any subprocess uses threads or other concurrent code, then use the `.getstate` and `setstate` calls around calls to random functions, guarding those with threading Locks, to avoid other threads to advance the generator state in the background

Comment: @jsbueno thank you, i keept one random generatorsby subprocess (initialized in the init fonction) but for each call of the task: 
- at the beginning i call seed and setstate
- at the end of the task i call getstate and store state into each object, so that each object and task run for it reused the previous step of the random at the start of the task !

Comment: Is the question solved based on the comment by @jsbueno? If so, somebody (@Progstud or @jsbueno) should write an acual answer.